# Bash script changing part of folder path on dynamic variable

Tags: bash, shell, file, directory

So i have put together the following bash script and i want to modify the file path directory i grab

So my layout is like so

```
/home/videos_test/categoryname/1/vid.mp4
/home/videos_test/categoryname/2/randomvid.mp4
```

and i want to modify the file path it grabs to look like this

```
/home/videos_test/changed_folder/1/vid.mp4
/home/videos_test/changed_folder/2/randomvid.mp4
```

Full script

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Type the category that you want, followed by [ENTER]:"

read category

export FILE_PATH="/home/videos_test"
export STAR="/*"

FILE_PATH=$FILE_PATH"/"$category;
echo $FILE_PATH;

minimumsize=1000

for dir in $FILE_PATH$STAR$STAR; do
[[ ! -f "${dir}" ]] && continue # if its NOT a file then skip
actualsize=$(du -k "$dir" | cut -f 1)
if [[ ! $actualsize -ge $minimumsize ]]; then #if file is less than 1mb delete it

echo $dir
echo size is under $minimumsize kilobytes
rm "$dir"
echo deleted

else #for files over 1mb in size convert with ffmpeg

full_file=$(basename $dir)
full_dir=$(dirname $dir)
echo $full_file
echo $full_dir

ffmpeg -i "$dir"

#ffmpeg output file directory needs to be mirrored but with a folder change

read -p "Press any key to resume ..."

fi
done
```

My folder output for ffmpeg i want to be

```
 /home/videos_test/$category _new/1/vid.mp4
/home/videos_test/$category _new/2/randomvid.mp4
```

Comment: what's the question? does the script run? does it generate an error (and if so, what's the error)? does the script do the 'wrong' thing (and if so what is it that it does 'wrong')? what's being supplied as the value for the `$category` variable ... `categoryname`, `change_folder` or something else?

Comment: read category is what the user inputs i just want the ffmpeg OUTPUT file to be something like the category name the user supplied but modified with something like _new appeneded to it

Comment: sorry, still don't understand what you're asking ... are you looking for help in modifying the `full_dir` variable to include the `_new` suffix, or how to redirect all `ffmpeg` output to a different directory?

Comment: i figured it out and posted my soloution as the answer i was trying to modify the $dir variable to a new path for ffmpeg to output files to

Comment: ok, so you just want to add the `_new` suffix ... easy enough to do with parameter substitution (assuming the string `$category` only shows up once in `$full_dir`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
path_start=$(echo $dir | rev | cut -d'/' -f4- | rev)
path_end=$(echo $dir | cut -d'/' -f5-)
new=_new
new_path=$path_start/$category$new/$path_end
new_path_no_file=$(echo $new_path | rev | cut -d'/' -f2- | rev)
mkdir -p $new_path_no_file
ffmpeg -i "$dir" -c:v copy -c:a copy -x264opts opencl -movflags +faststart -analyzeduration 2147483647 -probesize 2147483647 -pix_fmt yuv420p "$new_path"
```

Answer (score 2):

Assumptions:

- user provides a base directory (`read category`) containing some video files
- script needs to write converted files to new directory structure, replacing `${category}` (in the directory name) with `${category}_new`
- question is: how to add `_new` suffix to directory name

One idea is to use parameter substitution to create the new target directory name, and then use `mkdir -p` to create the new directory:

```
$ category=videos

$ full_dir="/some/parent/dir/${category}/subdir1/subdir2"
$ echo "${full_dir}"
/some/parent/dir/videos/subdir1/subdir2

$ new_dir="${full_dir//${category}/${category}_new}"
$ echo "${new_dir}"
/some/parent/dir/videos_new/subdir1/subdir2

$ [ -d "${new_dir}" ] 
$ echo $?
1                                # ${new_dir} does not exist

$ mkdir -p "${new_dir}"

$ [ -d "${new_dir}" ] 
$ echo $?
0                                # ${new_dir} does exist
```